# Using x64 version of Visual C++ toolset from IDE

Tags: visual-c++, cmake

How can I compile my program using the x64 toolset from the Visual Studio IDE? By default the IDE invokes the 32bit toolset when I press the "Build" button.

Additionally, how can I tell CMake to use the x64 toolset instead of the 32bit toolset?

Answer (score 0):

Please set your target property like this:

```
set_target_properties(MyTarget PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "-m64" LINK_FLAGS "-m64")
```

Answer (score 0):

The Visual Studio project generator for CMake needs to be told to generate a project for the 64-bit compiler toolchain.  Use `cmake -G "Visual Studio 2013 Win64"` for VS 2013 and x64 toolchain.  See the CMake documentation on generators like [Visual Studio 2013](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/manual/cmake-generators.7.html).